# Selecting a column from table including the default value

Tags: sql, oracle

I wonder if I can have a query which gives me the values of a column including the default value for the column. Is it doable?

I dont want to use union or joins.

For example, I have a table EMP as

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
 (EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20) DEFAULT 'XXX');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO EMP(EMP_NAME) VALUES('A');
INSERT INTO EMP(EMP_NAME) VALUES('B');
```

And when I query with something like

```
SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMP;
```

I want the result as

```
A
B
XXX
```

Business Logic:
The table EMP is the master table with the list of all employees. In an UI screen which I have my Oraganization task EG: ORG_TASK I have a UI screen with two columns, TASK_NAME, ASSINGED_EMPLOYEE and ASSINED_EMPLOYEE column is not NULLABLE for various other reasons.

So, when I want to create a new task, I just enter the task, its description in another column and need to choose the employee from a drop down in the ASSINED_EMPLOYEE column.

In case if the task cannot be assigned at that point of time to any of the employees, we want the drop down to also have a default value called TBD.

The source for the dropdown is a query which selects the employee names from the EMP table.
We want to append TBD to the values in the dropdown

Comment: Please provide more detail. What does the table look like? Provide some example rows in the table. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: You inserted 2 records but you want to select 3 records. It is not allowed kile this.

Comment: Updated my question with an example. Thanks.

Comment: The third row in your result set does not map to any row in your table.  So how do you think you can generate an additional row without using a join or union?  Magic?

Comment: @APC Definitely not majic. However, I did not post this question out of imagination but on a project I am working on. And, I have multiple workarounds to achieve this, creating views, union, join etc.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory.  We cannot generate a row in a result set without a join or something similar.  That applies whatever the query is, but especially to something which mixes data and metadata.  Perhaps if you edited your question to add the business logic and constraints perhaps we can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using only simple select statement. You can only take records which exist in your table.

You are looking for something like:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME FROM EMP
union all
select DATA_DEFAULT from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
and COLUMN_NAME = 'EMP_NAME';
```

But you have to find the way to convert `long` type to `varchar`.

It's not so simply just I've thought. It's good problem to ask new question on SO I think.

Comment: Thanks @Parado. However, I was looking for an alternative for union